# how to give an internal link to a submit button in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

this is a part of my index.html page which generates a from :

```
<form id="category_form" method="post" action="/wiki/">

            {% csrf_token %}


            {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.help_text }}
                {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}

           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Category" />
```

when i click submit button it stores the inputted value my model.what i want to do now is provide a link to this submit button so that when i click it it must input the value entered to my model as well as go to the link

i tried doing this :

```
<a href='content.html'>  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Category" /></a>
```

content.html is an another html view.the view.py which supply variables to content.html actually processes the values entered in that form above and returns some variable to content.html page
below is my index view

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = scrapform(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            print ('from.errors')
    else:
        form = scrapform()

    return render(request, 'wiki/index.html', {'form': form})
```

below is forms.py

```
LEVEL_CHOICES = (('beg','beginner'),('ind','inter'),('exp','expert'))
class scrapform(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(help_text="please enter the subject you desire")
    level = forms.CharField(max_length=128,widget=forms.Select(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES))
    time = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)

    class Meta:
        model = scrap
        fields = '__all__'
```

below is my content view

```
def content(request):
    subject = scrap.objects.values_list('subject', flat=True).distinct()
    level = scrap.objects.values_list('level', flat=True).distinct()
    time = scrap.objects.values_list('time', flat=True).distinct()
    page = wikipedia.page(subject)
    title = page.title
    content = page.content
    summary = page.summary
    html = page.html
    wiki_dict = {'summary':summary,'content':content,'title':title,'html':html}

    return render(request, 'wiki/content.html',wiki_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `redirect` in your views.py? Unless the link is dynamic, you should be able to easily achieve this in your views:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = scrapform(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # you don't actually need commit=True, that's the default behavior
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('url-for-content.html'))
```

Django doc for [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) and [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Comment: didn't worked, its shows the error Reverse for 'wiki/content.html' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] although the data are still being stored in my model

Comment: No I already pointed you to the `reverse` documentation and it should be easy to read. It's django's way to fetch the url string without explicitly hard code your url path. Your `wiki/content.html` is a file name not the url name for that view. Also the data storing in the model has nothing to do with redirection, it will always be stored because you did `form.save()`.

Comment: If you post your url definition of your `content.html` I can help you understand it a little better.

Comment: thanks,it helped for now.if i came u with further issues ill leave you a comment @Shang Wang